# Highcharts get table from range selected only

Tags: javascript, angular, charts, highcharts

I am writting this highchart in angular and I want to create my own range selector dynamically using this.chart.update. However it keeps saying undefined update not a function. How can I fix the code. Also, I am trying to export the dataTable into the graphTable div which is into a differnt tab. I have attached a image please help. [graph/tableview image][1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to get the data from the range selector events **rangeSelector.buttons.events**, you can also set your own datagrouping with **rangeSelector.buttons.dataGrouping**.

```
    rangeSelector: {
        buttons: [{
            type: 'month',
            count: 1,
            text: '1m',
            events: {
                click: function () {
                    console.log(this);
                }
            }
        },
    }
```

Demo:
https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/stock/rangeselector/button-click/

API References:
https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/rangeSelector.buttons.events
https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/rangeSelector.buttons.dataGrouping

Comment: THank you for the reply, but how would I get the 1m data? this.series.data does not work here.

Answer (score 0):

Implement inside **chart.events.load()** with this you are already close to getting data from other variables/sources and passing it inside the rangeSelector button events.

```
chart: {
  events: {
    load: function() {
      let chart = this,
        rangeSelector = chart.rangeSelector;
      console.log(chart);

      rangeSelector.update({
        buttons: [{
```

Demo:
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/Lgdhokfy/

API References:
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.load

Comment: That is, you want to select a given range for example: 1m and display them as a table. There is no direct way to retrieve data for a given range from the rangeSelector. What I meant was that you are able to pull from the whole object what was rendered, where the given points are.